# QuerySnapshot docs.length just return 0

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I was trying to make a clone of instagram, and I got to the part that I want to display the number of comments of the post using QuerySnapshot. My code is as follow:

```
int commentLen = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getComments();
  }

  void getComments() async {
    try {
      QuerySnapshot snap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('posts')
          .doc(widget.snap['postId'])
          .collection('comments')
          .get();
      commentLen = snap.docs.length;
    } catch (e) {
      showSnackBar(e.toString(), context);
    }
    setState(() {});
  }
```

The snap.docs.length just returns 0 even though there are comments in my "comments" subcollection. I cannot find a solution, please help.
Thank you

Comment: try `snap.size`

Comment: Can you try hardcoding the post ID like? `doc("idOfDocumentThatExists")` ?

Comment: 1) If you `print(commentLen)` right after `commentLen = snap.docs.length`, what does it show? 2) If that is not the value you expect, can you show why not? I.e. what is the value of `widget.snap['postId']` (print it too), and what documents are in the `comments` collection under that post?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen it shows 0, but in FireStore I have a collection of "comments" and 4 documents in it. The comments can be loaded on the comment screen, so I dont know what causes this issue

Comment: @Kundan it does not work either

Comment: Can you please check whether you have mentioned the “$commentLen” variable to "view all comments sections" in your code? If it's already defined please refer video from time frame 5:22 to 5:25 for the reference [here][1]. 

[1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mEPm9w5QlJM